# How to run a php script after the HTML has been fully rendered

Tags: php, html

I have a beginner php question:

Suppose I have a simple php file on my server creating some HTML, for example [this](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-StaFQ/0/1?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8). How can I run a php script that runs over the fully generated HTML code, after all other php scripts have finished, and modifies it? Lets say for example I want to turn all the `<li>` tags into `<p>` tags.

Should this be referenced in the php file itself, or is it better to implement it as an output filter? What is the standard way to call a script after the HTML is ready?

Thanks

--EDIT--

To clarify - I want the script to receive the final value of the HTML the server sends to the client - after all server side script have finished running (other PHP), but before any HTML/Javascript is executed on the server side, and output a modified version of it.

Comment: No, your PHP gets executed **before** any HTML or JavaScript. What you can do is, store the php script in another file and call it on `$(document).ready()` through AJAX.

Comment: This is something that can be done with Javascript - not PHP, but you can kind-of do something hacky with `file_get_contents($url)` if you really wanted.

Comment: I need this script to run on the server side, so Javascript is not an option..

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger - Is there not a way to call a PHP script that gets The final HTML as input and outputs it after processing?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at *output buffering* in PHP.

Here is a sample code that allows to replace *<li>* into *<p>* after generating HTML code and before sending it to the user:

```
ob_start();

echo '<html>';
    echo '<body>';
        echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li>List element 1</li>';
            echo '<li>List element 2</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';

$Html = ob_get_clean();

echo str_replace(array('<li>', '</li>'), array('<p>', '</p>'), $Html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a site explaining how to do this. Im going to leave this around for anyone with similar needs:

http://web.archive.org/web/20101216035343/http://dev-tips.com/featured/output-buffering-for-web-developers-a-beginners-guide